# custom action after installation failed

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installshield, custom-action

How to sequence a custom action to execute only when installation is interrupted or completed with error?

Is there any windows installer property which returns current installation status (failed/succeed)?

Answer (score 7):

The `OnExit` attribute of the [`<Custom>`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_custom.htm) element is what you're looking for. It is mutually exclusive with `Before`, `After`, and `Sequence` attributes and can have the following values: `success`, `cancel`, `error`, `suspend`.

**UPDATE**: basically, this is what I mean:

1) Define a custom action which will do the work you'd like it to do (gather some failure data). Note that you'll have to define N custom actions pointing to the same target because the [CustomAction MSI table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368062.aspx) expects `Id` as a primary key (let's assume it's DLL CA):

```
<CustomAction Id="LogFailureOnCancel" BinaryKey="CustomActions" DllEntry="LogFailure" ... />
<CustomAction Id="LogFailureOnError" BinaryKey="CustomActions" DllEntry="LogFailure" ... />
```

NOTE: both definitions point to the same **real** action (`DllEntry` attribute).

2) Schedule these custom actions appropriately:

```
 <Custom Action="LogFailureOnCancel" OnExit="cancel" />
 <Custom Action="LogFailureOnError" OnExit="error" />
```

Comment: Thanks Yan for suggesting solution. But i don't want return code of any particular custom action. To be more specific, if installations fails no matter which action(or custom action) throws error, i want to execute one custom action which collects some failure data from system and process it by sending it to server.

Comment: Hmm, I still think this can be achieved with the suggested solution... I'll update my answer to be more specific, and you'll see whether this is what you're looking for.

Comment: One more question Is there any windows installer property which gets set after successfully installing MSI or if any error occurs or user cancels the installation then contains error code.

Comment: I have never come across such a property

Answer (score 0):

To the extent that Windows Installer allows it, this is only possible during custom actions scheduled for rollback. However rollback only applies to the deferred script, so it's only available for actions scheduled between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize. If an immediate-mode action outside this scheduling window causes the installation to abort, rollback does not apply.

Assuming you're using a C++ or InstallScript action, you can find out if rollback is enabled, and if you're in rollback, with calls to [MsiGetMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370125.aspx) - using `MSIRUNMODE_ROLLBACKENABLED` or `MSIRUNMODE_ROLLBACK` respectively.